# Computer reset while partitioning specific hard drive, can't boot into Linux or Windows

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

My friend was partitioning a hard drive and it hung up for such a long time that he reset the computer while it was partitioning. Now, just plugging in the corrupted hard drive doesn't let ANY operating system boot. We've tried putting the hard drive in my computer and it won't let my computer load into Arch Linux or Windows. Arch Linux kernel panics while Windows 8 is stuck on the spinning wheel. When the corrupted hard drive isn't plugged into our computers, our computers function normally. Is there any hope for this 1TB hard drive?

Comment: As long as you are not booting from it you *should* be able to boot any OS from another drive and then take a look at the broken drive. With a bit of luck you can fix the partition table, or at least get a useful error message (either in the syslog or in the evenviewer).

Answer (score 1):

Download Ultimate Boot CD - http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

Put the Hard Drive back into a computer and boot into the CD and there are several utilities which should help you

There are numerous different things that could have happened. I would say the most likely is a corrupted Master Boot Record.

Hopefully the Data is backed up but worst case scenario and you need to format the disk and start again, UBCD should allow you to back the data up anyway.

There's numerous partition tool and a couple of MBR tools which would be where I looked first.